# PySide signals alternative using events not working

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I did something similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12127115/1433559).
The GUI is simple, you click a button which starts a thread that instead of emitting signals it sends events. The events cause a label to change text.

Here's the code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *
import sys, time

class MyEvent(QEvent):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(QEvent.User)
        self.message = message

class MyThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, widget):
        super().__init__()
        self._widget = widget

    def run(self):
        for i in range(10):
            app.sendEvent(self._widget, MyEvent("Hello, %s!" % i))
            time.sleep(.1)

class MyReceiver(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QLabel('Test!')
        start_button = QPushButton('Start thread')
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.startThread)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(start_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.User:
            self.label.setText(event.message)
            return True
        return False

    def startThread(self):
        self.thread = MyThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MyReceiver()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that, only the first event get processed by `MyReceiver`, then the widget freezes!.
Any clues?. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour of the `event` method of QWidget is altered in your code: you should
let the base class decide on what to do with events, not returning `False` if it is
not a custom event. Do it like this:

```
def event(self, event):
    if event.type() == QEvent.User:
        self.label.setText(event.message)
        return True
    return QWidget.event(self, event)
```

This fixes your problem.

Also, you may prefer to emit a Qt signal from the thread, and have it connected in
your widget to some method to change the label - signals and slots are thread-safe
in Qt 4 (contrary to Qt 3). It will achieve the same result.

Comment: Thanks, seems obvious. But I have actually tried sending events with `QApplication.notify()`, which should automatically propagate events, and it didn't work.

Comment: A careful reading of docs informs that propagation happens only for mouse and keyboard events, so that's why `event()` wasn't propagated.